# índice fora de intervalo c#

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer uma atribuição de valor em um determinado índice de uma String, porém, recebo o seguinte erro que não entendo o motivo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'O índice estava fora do intervalo. Ele deve ser não-negativo e menor que o tamanho da coleção.*'

```
        string tela;
        int counter = 0;
        StringBuilder telaBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        private void btnSendWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        char letra = Convert.ToChar(txtGetWord.Text);
        Boolean codigoVerificador;
        codigoVerificador =    verificador.VerificaLetra(comboPalavra[0],letra);
        if (codigoVerificador == true)
        {

        foreach(char c in comboPalavra[0].ToCharArray())
           {
                counter = counter + 1;
                if(c == letra)
                {

                    telaBuilder[counter] = Convert.ToChar( letra);
                    tela = telaBuilder.ToString();
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: A imagem não abre para mim. Prefira colocá-la diretamente dentro da sua pergunta fazendo o upload pelo Stack Overflow.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ela aparece pra você agora? Coloquei ela no imgur pra facilitar visualizar direto no site.

Comment: O que é `telaBuilder` e onde isso está declarado? Como você declara `counter`? Quando você usa `telaBuilder[counter]`, você acessa um array em uma posição inválida.

Comment: @Articuno Sim, agora aparece para mim.

Comment: @VictorStafusa adicionei as declarações

Comment: @VictorStafusa apenas esclarecendo, utilizei StringBuilder para tentar alterar um caracter de uma String, já que o C# não permite isso de maneira direta...Mas estou esbarrando nesse erro, parece obvio, mas não entendo o por que, o que pode ser?

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está tentando fazer com esse código. O que representa a letra que você está tentando colocar no `telaBuilder`?

Comment: Acho que o `StringBuilder` no ponto onde você está tentando alterar a letra está vazio.

Comment: O código é para um jogo da forca, então, quando o usuário entrar com uma letra e clicar no botão, essa letra será salva na variável "letra", e o telaBuilder é o objeto da StringBuilder que estou tentando utilizar para inserir essa letra na String do jogo da forca, caso o usuário acerte a letra...

Answer (score 1):

Você está a tentar atribuir uma letra a uma posição que não existe no StringBuilder.

Para fazer isso dessa forma deve inicializar o StringBuilder com um número de posições igual ao da palavra que quer descobrir:

```
private StringBuilder telaBuilder;
private int numeroDeLetras = 10;

...
...
telaBuilder = new StringBuilder(numeroDeLetras);
```

Por outro lado, tradicionalmente, o jogo costuma representar as letras ainda não encontradas com um `-`.

Para isso use

```
telaBuilder = new StringBuilder(new string('-', numeroDeLetras));
```

Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DFgmJO)

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, porém dá o seguinte erro: 

` a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property `

Comment: Se está a declarar as variáveis ao nível da classe, neste caso, não pode iniacializá-las.